# Is there anyway to change multiple working directories at the same time?

Tags: teamcity

I am using teamcity 2020.2.
If I have multiple build steps in one configuration, and I (or another user) want to chance the working directory of all of them to a same directory at the same time. Is there any way to achieve it?
Please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you can parametrize working dir
[image]

and then set in build run if its prompt parameter or change it in build settings if hidden